# Pass a List<int> from javascript to controller

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm trying to pass a `List<int>` from my `View` to my `Controller`. I've tried multiple ways, with different parameters. No luck.

I'm currently trying to pass `{[4,5,13]}` to a method with the parameter `List<int> ids`.

What's the correct format to send a list or array of numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that you have to pass in something like this:

```
{"ids":[4,5,13]}
```

If you are using AJAX, then I remember that I had to set `traditional` to true [(See the jquery ajax documentation)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) This was so that the parameters were able to be parsed properly.

Comment: Scratch that. You can actually send in the javascript array object if you turn on the `traditional` option.

Comment: @DoctorOreo Yup, that is what kept getting me. I had to pull out Fiddler to figure that one out :) Glad it was helpful to somebody else

Answer (score 3):

The AJAX way:

From the jquery documentation for [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> #### data
>
> **Type:** PlainObject or String 
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to
>   the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this
>   automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an
>   Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the
>   value of the traditional setting (described below).
>
> #### traditional
>
> **Type:** Boolean 
> Set this to true if you wish to use the
>   traditional style of [param serialization](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param).

```
var roleList = new Array();
var usrId = "testuser";

/* one  way of adding items to array */
roleList.push(1);
roleList.push(5);
roleList.push(8);

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true, /* I M P O R T A N T */
            url: /* url to controller goes here */,
            data: { userId: usrId, allowedRoles: roleList },
            success: function(returndata) {
                alert("Done");
            },
            error: function(returndata) {
                alert("Error:\n" + returndata.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: traditional: true, /* I M P O R T A N T */ does the job. thanks!